# How pass named arguments with parameters to aws batch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cloudformation, aws-batch

Consider piece of AWS batch job definition:

```yaml
    MyJobDefinition:
        Type: "AWS::Batch::JobDefinition"
        Properties:
            Type: container
            Parameters: {}
            JobDefinitionName: "my-job-name"
            ContainerProperties:
                Command:
                    - "java"
                    - "-jar"
                    - "my-application-SNAPSHOT.jar"
                    - "--param1"
                    - "Ref::param1"
                    - "--param2"
                    - "Ref::param2"
```

Which result to call:

```
java -jar my-application-SNAPSHOT.jar --param1 someValue1 --param2 someValue2
```

How do I change job definition to make it like this? (notice the `=` sign):

```
java -jar my-application-SNAPSHOT.jar --param1=someValue1 --param2=someValue2
```

Please note that `Ref::param1` is not cloudformation template params, but [aws batch job params](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/job_definition_parameters.html#parameters).

Comment: It is worth mentioning param1 and param2 in the Paremeters json field, so that it is clear, that those do not come from template params.

Comment: Why don't you pass values as "java -jar my-application-SNAPSHOT.jar someValue1 someValue2"?

Comment: Did you end up refactoring the code and passing in the arguments directly instead of using application.properties?

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can pass environment variables using the -D option when running your application from the command line.Replace param1 with the name of your environment variable, and param1_value with the actual value you want to assign to it.

```
  MyJobDefinition:
            Type: "AWS::Batch::JobDefinition"
            Properties:
                Type: container
                Parameters: {}
       
    
         JobDefinitionName: "my-job-name"
            ContainerProperties:
                Command:
                    - "java"
                    - "-Dparam1=${param1_value}"
                    - "-Dparam2={param2_value}"
                    - "-Dparam3={param2_value}"
                    - "-jar"
                    - "my-application-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

For example, if you have an environment variable named DATABASE_URL and you want to pass its value to your Java application, you can use:

```
java -DDATABASE_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname -jar YourApplication.jar
```

In your Java application, you can access the environment variable value using the System.getProperty() method:

```
String databaseUrl = System.getProperty("DATABASE_URL");
```

The databaseUrl variable will contain the value passed from the command line. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

As I understand, AWS batch parameters are substituted by looking for the Ref:: prefix. I could find only one [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=801228&#801228) where they tried to use a parameter in a larger string and it works.

Given that, the following should work

```
MyJobDefinition:
    Type: "AWS::Batch::JobDefinition"
    Properties:
        Type: container
        Parameters: {}
        JobDefinitionName: "my-job-name"
        ContainerProperties:
            Command:
                - "java"
                - "-jar"
                - "my-application-SNAPSHOT.jar"
                - "--param1=Ref::param1"
                - "--param2=Ref::param2"
```

Comment: This is wrong. Batch does not support substitution inside strings. Only for complete arguments.